# Actionscript Loader Error #1009

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm trying to make a basic loader that uses Splash.swf to then load myisogame.swf

I keep getting error #1009. It's a template we was given in class, originally the Splash.swf directed to Game.swf, but in the code below there is only one mention of where it directs to.

In the template Game.fla doesn't have any code in it.

Here is the Splash

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;

    public class Splash extends MovieClip {

        var myLoader:Loader;
        var loadingAnim:LoadingAnimation;
        var percentLoaded:TextField =new TextField();

        public function Splash() {
            // constructor code
            myLoader = new Loader();
            myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);
            myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);

            var blubox = new BluBox();
            addChild(blubox);
            blubox.x=200;
            blubox.y=200;

            loadingAnim = new LoadingAnimation();
            addChild(loadingAnim);
            loadingAnim.x=200;
            loadingAnim.y=200;
            loadingAnim.scaleX=0;

            var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
            format.font = "Verdana";
            format.color = 0xFF0000;
            format.size = 20;
            format.underline = false;

            percentLoaded.defaultTextFormat = format;

            addChild(percentLoaded);
            percentLoaded.x=200;
            percentLoaded.y=230;
            myLoader.load(new URLRequest("myisogame.swf"));
        }

        function onProgress(evt:ProgressEvent):void {   

            var nPercent:Number = Math.round((evt.bytesLoaded / evt.bytesTotal) * 100);    
            loadingAnim.scaleX = nPercent / 100;
            percentLoaded.text = nPercent.toString() + "%";
            trace("load%"+nPercent.toString());
        }

        function onComplete(evt:Event):void {
            myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);
            myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete); 
            loadingAnim.x=1000;
            addChild(myLoader);
        }



        function onIOError(evt:IOErrorEvent):void {
            trace("IOError loading SWF");
            }
    }

}



5    
6   
7    
8   
11   
12  
13   
14  
20   

25   
26
```

MyIsoGame code

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import as3isolib.display.scene.IsoScene;
    import as3isolib.display.IsoView;
    import as3isolib.display.scene.IsoGrid;
    import as3isolib.graphics.Stroke;
    import as3isolib.display.primitive.IsoBox;
    import as3isolib.display.IsoSprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import eDpLib.events.ProxyEvent;
    import as3isolib.geom.Pt;
    import as3isolib.geom.IsoMath;
    import as3isolib.graphics.SolidColorFill;

// before class


    public class MyIsoGame extends MovieClip {

        public var scene:IsoScene;
        public var view:IsoView ;
        public var CELLSIZE:int = 30;//------This is very important to remember cell size. This will affect placement of objects

        var zoomFactor:Number = 1;////Zoom Factor heerrrreee--------------------
        var s1:IsoSprite = new IsoSprite();
        var wr:IsoSprite = new IsoSprite();
        var wre:IsoSprite = new IsoSprite();
        var g1:IsoSprite = new IsoSprite();
        var b1:IsoSprite = new IsoSprite();
        var b2:IsoSprite = new IsoSprite();
        var b3:IsoSprite = new IsoSprite();



        public function MyIsoGame() {
            // constructor code
            trace("hello from constructor");

            scene = new IsoScene();

            view = new IsoView();
            view.setSize((stage.stageWidth), stage.stageHeight);
            view.clipContent = true;
            view.showBorder = false;

            view.addScene(scene); 
            view.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onStartPan, false, 0, true);
            view.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, onZoom, false, 0, true);




            addChild(view);


            var g:IsoGrid = new IsoGrid();
            g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gridClick);
            g.cellSize=30;
            g.setGridSize(6,6);
            g.y=0;
            g.x=0;
            g.gridlines = new Stroke(2,0x666666);


            g.showOrigin = false;       
            scene.addChild(g);

            g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, grid_mouseHandler);

            var box:IsoBox = new IsoBox();
            box.setSize(10, 10, 10);
            box.moveTo(50,50,0);
            scene.addChild(box);


            wr.setSize(30, 30, 30);
            wr.moveTo(60, 0, 0);
            wr.sprites=[new Wrecked()];
            scene.addChild(wr);

            wre.setSize(30, 30, 30);
            wre.moveTo(30, 0, 0);
            wre.sprites=[new Wrecked()];
            scene.addChild(wre);

            g1.setSize(30, 30, 30);
            g1.moveTo(150, 150, 0);
            g1.sprites=[new Gold()];
            scene.addChild(g1);

            b1.setSize(30, 30, 30);
            b1.moveTo(120, 120, 0);
            b1.sprites=[new Blue()];
            scene.addChild(b1);


            b2.setSize(30, 30, 30);
            b2.moveTo(120, 150, 0);
            b2.sprites=[new Blue()];
            scene.addChild(b2);

            b3.setSize(30, 30, 30);
            b3.moveTo(150, 120, 0);
            b3.sprites=[new Blue()];
            scene.addChild(b3);




            scene.render();

            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL,mouseWheel);///MOUSE WHEEL CONTROL

            stage.addEventListener (KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyboarddownlistener)
        }


        private function gridClick(event:ProxyEvent):void
        {
            var me:MouseEvent = MouseEvent(event.targetEvent);
            var p:Pt = new Pt(me.localX, me.localY);
            IsoMath.screenToIso(p);
y

            }


        private var panPt:Pt;
private function onStartPan(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    panPt = new Pt(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY);

    view.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onStartPan);

    view.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onPan, false, 0, true);
    view.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onStopPan, false, 0, true);
}

private function onPan(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    view.panBy(panPt.x - stage.mouseX, panPt.y - stage.mouseY);

    panPt.x = stage.mouseX;
    panPt.y = stage.mouseY;
}
private function boxClick(e:Event) 
            {
                    view.centerOnIso(e.target as IsoBox);
                }


private function onStopPan(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    view.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onPan);
    view.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onStopPan);

    view.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onStartPan, false, 0, true);
}


private var zoomValue:Number = 1;
private function onZoom(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(e.delta > 0)
        zoomValue +=  0.10;

    if(e.delta < 0)
        zoomValue -=  0.10;

    view.currentZoom = zoomValue;
}




        ///----------------Grid Mouse Handler
        public function grid_mouseHandler (evt:ProxyEvent):void
    {
        var mEvt:MouseEvent = MouseEvent(evt.targetEvent);
        var pt:Pt = new Pt(mEvt.localX, mEvt.localY);
        IsoMath.screenToIso(pt);
        var roundedX:int = int(pt.x)/30;
        var roundedY:int=  int(pt.y)/30;
        trace("transformed point = "+roundedX +","+roundedY);


///Code that allows things to be put down, located here.        
        var s:IsoSprite= new IsoSprite(); 
        s.sprites=[new Base()];
        s.setSize(30, 30, 30);//Varies via Cell size-
        s.moveTo(roundedX*30, roundedY*30, 0);
        scene.addChild(s);
        scene.render();


    }///------------------Grid Mouse Handler


        public function mouseWheel (event:MouseEvent){
            trace("The Delta value isss: " + event.delta);
            //Get current view zoom
            zoomFactor+=event.delta*0.04;
            view.zoom(zoomFactor)
        }



        public function keyboarddownlistener(e:KeyboardEvent){

            {//Screen-Movement Code
                if (e.keyCode == 40)
                {// The numbers represent the keyboard buttons
                trace("Down Arrow")// I've left these trace commands so you can get a better idea of which one is what.-William 22/04/14
                view.pan(0,5);
                scene.render();
                //Down arrow???
                }
            }

            if (e.keyCode == 38)
            {
                trace("Up Arrow")
                view.pan(0,-5);
                scene.render();
                //Up arrow???
            }

                if (e.keyCode == 37)
            {
                trace("Left Arrow")
                view.pan(5,0);
                scene.render();
                //Left arrow???
            }

                if (e.keyCode == 39)
            {
                trace("Right Arrow")
                view.pan(-5,0);
                scene.render();
                //Right arrow???
            }

            /////OBJECT MOVEMENT code- For moving the donut around
            ///-- I am going to be working on a version of this game where--
            ///- everything can be controlled via a Keyboard only -William 22/04/14
        if (e.keyCode == 65)
            {
                trace("A Left <--")
                //view.x+=15;//Alternate version
                s1.moveBy(30,0,0)
                scene.render();
                //Left?
            }
            if (e.keyCode == 68)
            {
                trace("D Right -->")
                //view.x-=15;//Alternate version
                s1.moveBy(-30,0,0)
                scene.render();
                //Right?
            }

            if (e.keyCode == 83)
            {
                trace("S Down --v")
                //view.x-=15;//Alternate version
                s1.moveBy(0,30,0)
                scene.render();
                //Down?
            }

            if (e.keyCode == 87)
            {
                trace("W Up --^")
                //view.x-=15;//Alternate version
                s1.moveBy(0,-30,0)
                scene.render();
                //Up? 
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code you supplied (without the numbers at the bottom) and it worked just fine for me.

error #1009 is a runtime error when you use a variable that hasn't been defined yet. I would suggest debugging from Flash Pro (ctrl + shift +enter) and let it show you where it breaks.

In your FLA, you said there is no code, but in the properties panel you do see the class field with "Splash" in it right? that is what links the class to the FLA.

It is possible that the runtime error you are seeing is not in the Splash class but in either BluBox or LoadingAnimation.  Do those have class files?  If not, take a look in the Library and you'll have two movie clips that are exported for actionScript with those names.  Check in them to see if there might be some framescript.

Comment: The template that I was given was called game and the Splash loaded up 'game', game didn't have any code in it. What i've done is take the splash and added it to 'MyIsoGame'

BluBox and LoadingAnimation class files just have the basic starting class code.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  To create what I did to test it (which worked), I made an FLA and gave it the doc class Splash.  I then created a class file Splash.as and pasted your code into it and saved it to the same directory as the FLA.  Back in the FLA I made 2 movieclips in the library. I set them each to export for ActionScript and made the class BluBox for one and LoadingAnimation for the other.  I did not create class files for and let implicitly create them.  After that, I created a new FLA names MyISOGame and saved to the same dir.  Export the game, then export the splash.

Comment: LoadingAnimation is a button, could this be what's causing the problem? I'll try what you suggested here and see if that changes anything :)

Comment: Unless it's something in my game code that is blocking the Splash? I edited the main part of this thread with the MyIsoGame's code

Comment: to test if it is the game, try loading a different SWF that doesn't have any code in it (just something on the stage so you can see it).  If LoadingAnimation is a button, there is probably an event listener somewhere either as frame script or in LoadingAnimation.as.  If you have the button on the stage already in the LoadingAnimation and you try to talk to that button in the constructor, you'd get the error because the constructor is run before frame 1 is initialized.  You would need to listen for the event onAddedToStage

Comment: I made a new swf file called 'FLOPP' and it loaded that without any problems. Hm

Comment: ok, so the issue is your constructor for the game.  At the end you add stage.addEventListner.  stage doesn't exist yet at construction.  It will exist once it is is added to the stage. Easy change:  create a new function called init that takes one param (Event) and copy your constructor code into it.  Now, in your empty constructor, write: `addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);`  Recompile the game, and then test your loader again

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment on the BotMaster's comment above, so I'm doing it here.  The issue is a runtime error, not a compiler error.  If Botmaster had really read the question it would have been clear.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Only problem now is that the loading bar is still there when the game is loaded :/

Comment: once loaded, just remove BluBox and LoadingAnimation from stage, remove any event listeners and remove any references to it (like variables).  Removing it from stage will make it visually go away. The other parts will allow the garbage collector to remove it from memory.  Also, if either of those objects is playing audio be sure to stop those before removing the movie clips since they audio would continue playing even when off stage.

Comment: Tried doing stage.removeChild(loadingAnim); in the onComplete function of the loader.as but throws up another error, loads the game and still has the loading bar :(

Comment: ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
 at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
 at Splash/onComplete()

Comment: try "this" instead of "stage"